# How to fix "TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'"?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner JavaScript programmer and I am following a book called "Create with < code >" and I am having trouble with the code. I have been following along with the book but when I have tried running it, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)

I have been typing the code into a plain-text editor and viewing it on Chrome. How do I fix this error?

If you run the snippet you should be able to see the error.

```js
//CONSTANTS
var CANVAS_WIDTH = 800;
var CANVAS_HEIGHT = 600;

var GROUND_Y = 540;

//SETUP
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var cameraX = 0;
var bushData = generateBushes();

var bush1Image = new Image();
bush1Image.src = 'bush1.png';

var bush2Image = new Image();
bush2Image.src = 'bush2.png';

window.addEventListener('load', start);

function start() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

function generateBushes() {
    var generatedBushData = [];
    var bushX = 0;
    while (bushX < (2 * CANVAS_WIDTH)) {
        var bushImage;
        if (Math.random() >= 0.5) {
            bushImage = bush1Image;
        } else {
            bushImage = bush2Image
        }
        generatedBushData.push({
            x: bushX,
            y: 80 + Math.random() * 20,
            image: bushImage
        });
        bushX += 150 + Math.random() * 200;
    }
    return generatedBushData;
}

//MAIN LOOP
function mainLoop() {
    update();
    draw();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);

}

//UPDATING
function update() {

    //Update bushes.
    for (var i = 0; i < bushData.length; i++) {
        if ((bushData[i].x - cameraX) < -CANVAS_WIDTH) {
            bushData[i].x += (2 * CANVAS_WIDTH) + 150;
        }
    }
}

//DRAWING
function draw() {

    //Draw the bushes
    for (var i = 0; i < bushData.length; i++) {
        c.drawImage(
            bushData[i].image,
            bushData[i].x,
            GROUND_Y - bushData[i].y);
    }

}
```

Comment: The error is: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)' and it is on line 163.

Comment: If I search on that error, I get a **lot** of hits. Have you read through those various pages to see if they answer your problem?

Comment: Yes, I have looked through a couple of the pages but none seemed to help. I have stripped the code back so it is easier to understand and still has the same error. Does this make it any easier?

Comment: The error is on this line:
`c.drawImage(bushData[i].image, bushData[i].x, GROUND_Y - bushData[i].y);`

The *bushData* variable contains an array of objects like that: `{x: number, y: number, image: undefined}` since *image* is undefined it cannot be drawn on canvas. you are missing the part in which those properties shoul be initialized.

Comment: @DanieleAlessandra ,but I have the images on in the same folder as the html document and i have defined the image in this part: `generatedBushData.push({
                    x: bushX,
                    y: 80 + Math.random() * 20,
                    image: bushImage`  
right?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - How do you suggest I change the question? I can't just put Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas) into the question, right?

Comment: (That's my reopen vote, btw, from a few minutes ago. I did it because of the changes you made and on the assumption you're putting the error in the question.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I tried changing the title but there is a 150 character limit. The error alone is 245 characters.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Got it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @DanieleAlessandra put his finger on the error: `image` in those objects is indeed `undefined`, because you're calling `generateBushes` too soon. You have `var bushData = generateBushes(); var bush1Image = new Image(); bush1Image.src = 'bush1.png'; var bush2Image = new Image(); bush2Image.src = 'bush2.png';` but you need to initialize `bush1Image` and `bush2Image` **before** calling `generateBushes`. Just moving `var bushData = generateBushes();` to after `bush2Image.src = 'bush2.png';` fixes it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - That fixes it! Thank you for your time and effort. Is there a way to mark your answer as top answer and close the question?

Comment: J2t0n4 - There is now that the question's been reopened. :-) I've posted a community wiki answer, since it was a combined effort with @DanieleAlessandra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DanieleAlessandra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2473909/danielealessandra) put his finger on the error in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811717/how-to-fix-typeerror-failed-to-execute-drawimage-on-canvasrenderingcontext2?noredirect=1#comment94472259_53811717): `image` in the objects in `bushData` is `undefined`, because you're calling `generateBushes` too soon. You have:

```
var bushData = generateBushes();

var bush1Image = new Image();
bush1Image.src = 'bush1.png';

var bush2Image = new Image();
bush2Image.src = 'bush2.png';
```

but you need to initialize `bush1Image` and `bush2Image` **before** calling `generateBushes`. Just moving `var bushData = generateBushes();` to after `bush2Image.src = 'bush2.png';` fixes it.